# pass thin spaces from javascript function to html in a vue filter:

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Specifically here, I want to pass one of these thin spaces between the dollar sign and the price in the filter below:

```
U+2009  THIN SPACE
U+2006  SIX-PER-EM SPACE
U+200A  HAIR SPACE

filters: {
    currency: function(price) {
        return "$".concat(price.toFixed(2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use one of the following character entities

```
<!-- thin -->
&thinsp; 
&ThinSpace; 
&#x02009;
&#8201;

<!-- hair -->
&hairsp;
&VeryThinSpace;
&#x0200A;
&#8202;
```

source : https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref